# How to delete all ._ files?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, files

I recently replaced the default macOS (El Capitan) with Ubuntu 16.10 (on a MacBook Pro 11.1, and backed up all my documents to an external drive.

When I migrated all my documents back from the drive, I ended up with a lot of `._` files (including `._DS_Store`, `._.DS_Store`, and copies of several documents starting with `._` followed by the original document name.

I would like to get rid of all those files. I tried Bleachbit, but that one apparently only finds the `._DS_Store` files, not the other types. I am especially interested in figuring out a way to safely delete all these ._ duplicates of my documents. Also, all these `._` files are scattered around on several different folders and sub-folders, so I would like to be able to make a system-wide search to spot them and delete them, without deleting anything that I actually care about.

Could anyone recommend the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Very carefully.  Typoing this is possibly the most common way to accidentally erase your hard drive.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using `find`, from the parent, recursively:

```
find . -type f -name '._*'
```

After checking append `-delete` to remove the files:

```
find . -type f -name '._*' -delete
```

---

Using `bash`, from parent directory:

```
shopt -s globstar  ## Enables recursive glob match
for f in **/._*; do [[ -f $f ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

After checking, do:

```
for f in **/._*; do [[ -f $f ]] && rm "$f"; done
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly. I'll accept the answer as soon as the site lets me...